# I cannot understand object manipulation in python

Tags: python, class, object, recursion

I tried to implement a queue using 2 stacks using the code below.

Utility Stack implementation.

```
class Stack():
    def __init__(self,array = []):
        self.array = array

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.array == []

    def pop(self):
        if self.array == []:
            raise Exception('stack is empty')
        else:
            popped_element = self.array.pop()
            return popped_element

    def push(self,key):
        self.array.append(key)

    def top(self):
        return self.array[-1]

    def __repr__(self):
        return " ".join(list(map(str,self.array)))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Stack()
    q.push(1)
    q.push(2)
    q.push(3)
    q.push(4)
    q.push(5)
    print(q.pop())
    print(q.pop())
    print(q.pop())
    q.push(10)
    print(q)
```

```
from stack import Stack
class TwoStackQueue1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack1 = Stack()
        self.stack2 = Stack()

    def enqueue(self,key):
        self.stack1.push(key)

    def dequeue(self):
        while(self.stack1.is_empty() != True):
            top = self.stack1.top()
            print("eval_dequeue",top)
            self.stack2.push(top)
            self.stack1.pop()


        if self.stack2.is_empty() == True:
            raise Exception("Queue is empty")
        else:
            top = self.stack2.pop()
            return top

    def is_empty():
        return self.stack1.is_empty() and self.stack2.is_empty()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = TwoStackQueue1()
    q.enqueue(1)
    q.enqueue(2)
    q.enqueue(3)
    q.enqueue(4)
    q.enqueue(5)
    print(q.stack1)
    print(q.dequeue())
```

when i tried to perform above operations on the queue , my code is getting stuck in infinite recursion because pop operation of my stack is not working . 
Can someone please help me figure out why my code (Queue operations:- q.dequeue()) is getting stuck in infinite recursion?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: And please allow me the comment that your Stack is nothing more than a reimplementation of some functions lists (they are not called arrays) already have.

Comment: @KlausD.Thanks for the link , it solved my problem. I'm totally aware of the fact that the Stack class is nothing more than append and pop functions of the list. I created the class because I wanted to have an abstraction similar to stacks in other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have effectively made the inner state of your object a Singleton, by virtue of the fact that you used a [mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/418413).

In other words, since the *array* you can initialize your Stack with is the empty list by default, any future instance will not just use *an* empty list, but will use the *same* list as all previous Stack instances.

Try this quick fix:

```
class Stack():
    def __init__(self,array=None):
        self.array = array or []
    ...
```